# Rendering a dropdown Menu in Backbone

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, haml

I am new to Backbone and am trying to stumble my way through it.  At the moment I have a view that renders a json hash into a dropdown menu. When I inspect the element in the browser I can actual view the UL element with all of the JSON rendered into a list, yet nothing visually appears in the browser. It should be noted that I am using twitter bootstrap to build the dropdown menu. Any help is much appreciated.

```
App.Views.FilterView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
  _.bindAll(this, 'render');
  this.$button = this.$('.dropdown');
  this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
},

render: function(){
  html = _.template(this.template());
  this.$el.html(html);
},

template: function() {
  var criteria = initial_data.criteria_hash.servers.criteria;    
  var list = "";

  for(var i = 0;  i < criteria.length; i++){
    list += "<li role=\"presentation\">" + criteria[i]  + "</li>";
  }
  return "<ul class='criteria-list dropdown-menu' role=\"menu\">" + list + "</ul>";
  }
});
```

Here is the HAML:

```
    %h2.beta Reports 
      .criteria-container
        .dropdown
          %button.btn.btn-default.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown"}
            Search Criteria
            %span.caret
```

Comment: Are you initializing your drop down anywhere? for example at the end of your render function `this.$el.find('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()`

Comment: no, I tried that, but it doesnt seem to make a difference

Comment: Can you create a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: hmm http://jsfiddle.net/rrFSF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are overwriting part of the markup for your drop-down. In your render function you are retuning just the markdown for the `ul` but you are overwriting the entire `el`.

If you include the markup for the button in your template function it should work

```
template: function() {
    var criteria = initial_data.criteria_hash.servers.criteria;   
    var list = "";

    for(var i = 0;  i < criteria.length; i++){
      list += "<li role=\"presentation\">" + criteria[i]  + "</li>";
    }
    return "<button class=\"btn btn-default dropdown-toggle\"  data-toggle=\"dropdown\">Search criteria<span class=\"caret\"></span></button><ul class='criteria-list dropdown-menu' role=\"menu\">" + list + "</ul>";
  }
});
```

And here's a link to a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hagohuho/2/)

You might also find it easier to separate the markup of your template and either place it in a script tag in your html page or an external page.

Comment: Nice! Now I have it in the browser, but the dropdown itself seems busted

Comment: Sorry I haven't really worked with bootstrap, but I suspect that the markup is off. First see if you can get your drop down looking as you want by itself (that is without rendering dynamically).

Comment: It looks like I linked to an older version of bootstrap, I updated the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hagohuho/2/) and the drop-down seems to look correctly now.

Comment: it turned out to be a binding error on backbone's part, thanks again for all your help